# c# .net ConfigurationManager is broken

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, encryption, connection-string, configurationmanager

I broke configurationManager by mistake . I just tried to secure my connectionstring, but now I am not even able to get normal human readable connectionstring from configuration manager, I just tried some commands in vs2012 command prompt like sapnet_regiiis pef ....bla bla bla , and now when I just try toget connectionstring from configurationmanager it throws an exception  ,                  **Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened.**  ....[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow access to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder then this problem is handled successfully. right click on the MachineKeys folder ->properties then ->sharing then add everyone ,or aspnet user then you solved the problem.